# TabHost inside a fragment of an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I want to create a layout in which upper half is just some area with normal views and lower half is a tab layout .

[image: something like this]

I've seen some examples but they're all how to create tabs at activity level i.e by extending TabHostActivity which covers all the activity area.
So i decided to create 2 fragments in the activity ,in which lower fragment will have the tablayout.
But the problem is i cant make this fragment class extend Fragment as well as TabHostActivity...
So any help how could i implement this ?

Here's the lower fragment's code -

```
public class PFrag extends Fragment {
    View mRoot;
    TabHost tabHost;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payfrag, container, false);
        try {
            Resources resources = getResources();
            tabHost = (TabHost)mRoot.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

            Intent netbintent = new  Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), NB.class);
            TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecNB = tabHost.newTabSpec("NB");
            tabSpecNB.setIndicator("", resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.netb));
            tabSpecNB.setContent(netbintent);

            Intent ccardintent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Cc.class);
            TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecCc = tabHost.newTabSpec("CC");
            tabSpecCc.setIndicator("", resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.cc));
            tabSpecCc.setContent(ccardintent);


            tabHost.addTab(tabSpecNB);
            tabHost.addTab(tabSpecCc);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            ad.setMessage(e.toString());
            ad.show();
        }

        return mRoot;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find an answer to your problem?

Comment: nah , i was in a bit of hurry to complete the project , just changed the layout -_-   , used simple tabbed layout instead of fragment
Will surely try it out and post answer as soon as i get it  :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use  [FragmentTabHost](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html) inside your "bottom" fragment.

Another link that could help you out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529267/how-to-add-tabhost-in-fragments).

Also, it seems on only work in API 17 and above, so be sure to keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0):

I will not recommend `FragmentTabHost` its somehow difficult to use and don't have swipe Left-Right. `TabHostActivity` is also deprecated, use `SlidingTabLayout` its open source and easily to use and update and have swipe.

[SlidingTabLayout](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html)