# FragmentTabHost Setup Error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, fragment-tab-host, android-nested-fragment

I'm trying to implement a nested fragment with the `FragmentTabHost`, however I keep getting an error with the `setup()` function. Code is below.

This is My Class File

```
public class ForumFragment extends Fragment{
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
public ForumFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forum,container,false);


    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(),android.R.id.tabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("DBoard"), DiscussionBoardFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Events"), EventsFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("HW Help"), HWHelpFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4").setIndicator("Classifieds"), ClassifiedsFragment.class, null);

    return view;

}
```

Here is my XML File

```
<TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/tabhost">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/DBoard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Events"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/HWHelp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Classifieds"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And here is the error I'm receiving

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.setup(android.content.Context, android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.ForumFragment.onCreateView(ForumFragment.java:30)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Use `R.id.tabhost` instead of `android.R.id.tabhost`

Comment: I get an unexpected cast error when I change it to R.id.tabhost

Comment: instead of `getChildFragmentManager()`, you should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` for more help see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Comment: That link is what I was using as reference, and there getChildFragmentManager() is used ..

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(),android.R.id.tabcontent);
```

to

```
mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getSupportFragmentManager(),android.R.id.tabcontent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:
  `mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);`

You need to inflate your own `R` file and not `android.R`. Just change it to:

`mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);`

and in XML file change the `<TabHost` to `<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost`

Comment: When I change android.R to just R.id. I get a typecast error.

Comment: Yes, you need to cast to TabHost, not FragmentTabHost. See the edited answer. Also declare mTabHost as TabHost

Comment: @LuciusHipan he is using `FragmentTabHost` and according to that he has written write code see this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html There is one mistake, instead of `getChildFragmentManager()`, he should use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: you're right, can you add your answer ? or edit mine?

Comment: Using getSupportFragmentManager() I get an error as well , is there anything I should import?

Comment: are your Fragment is from support library ? Be sure you imported correct Fragment class

Comment: Yes, I imported     import android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: I'm still receiving the same error @LuciusHipan ! -_- , I can't use the getSupportFragmentManger() because I'm not deriving FragmentActivity within my class. I'm using the nested fragment way with my app.

Comment: try the fix I put now in answer, please.

Comment: @LuciusHipan Ok I tried that it gives me a rendering problem and will not display in the design view, however when I run the app it compiles with no errors BUT the tabs are not being displayed. The text of what suppose to be displayed in the tab is displayed.

Comment: oh, now I've got you. please look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13461126/2031068

Comment: Thanks , that did help with the setup() error problem but the tabs are still not being displayed on the screen when I run the app.

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert your fragment to **android.support.v4.app.Fragment** because you are using **android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost** and it is **support only android.support.v4.app.Fragment.**

read this line  **android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.setup(android.content.Context, android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, int)**

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio does not provide dependencies so you will have to import them manually. File > Project Structure > app (under “Modules) > Dependencies tab. Click the “+” at the bottom to add a Library Dependency; in this case “support-v4“.