# how to load tabhost in a fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, fragment-tab-host

helle everyone. please Iwant to know how to build tabhost in a fragment. I want to have the following hierarchy: naviagation drawer -> fragment and in the fragment I load the tabhost. if anyone can help me I waiting please

Comment: i have post some code with example try it.

Comment: put your efforts.where is your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add tabhost in fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529267/how-to-add-tabhost-in-fragments)

Comment: good question ,I upvoted you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this.

You should use TabLayout instead of TabHost.

Make Xml for  main fragment which content Tabs.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then Make Code like below:

```
public class TabsFragment extends Fragment {

View view;
PagerAdapter adapter;

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

///Here we have to pass ChildFragmentManager instead of FragmentManager.
      adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "Fragment1");
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "Fragment2");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_tabslayout, container, false);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

    }

    static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please the "ButterKnife" make error in the onCreateView how can I fix it ?

Comment: @ArseneLeVirtu-oseDjeukam i have Updated my code . you have to just replace this to getActivity();

Comment: like this ? getActivity().bind(this, view);

Comment: Butterknife.bind(getActivity(),view);

Comment: its does this in addition to the old error
Error:(26, 16) error: method addFragment in class Adapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: Fragment,String
found: Fragment1,String
reason: actual argument Fragment1 cannot be converted to Fragment by method invocation conversion

Comment: and the old was: Error:(46, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable ButterKnife

Comment: have you create Fragment class for each tabs which you want to show?

Comment: have you extend v4 Fragments?

Comment: check your imports you have seen app.Fragment

Comment: when you are using Fragment Then there is two  lib available you have to use V4 lib fragment

Comment: import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

Comment: this  site is not for teach you . its for help to solve query you are beginner you should first go through tutorials.

Comment: remove import android.app.Fragment; you get error on Fragment  then click on it and press alt+enter you get two package in that select v4 one

Comment: ok I have done it thx but I got the same error with the "ButterKnife"   Error:(35, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable ButterKnife

Comment: have you add Butterknifelib In Gradle?

Comment: and why you use ButterKnife Lib.?

Comment: when I add a have this error  Error:(37, 20) error: cannot find symbol method bind(FragmentActivity,View)  and this  Error:(48, 28) error: cannot find symbol variable getActivity

Comment: please the different fregment are empty yet their different xml file is well been designer. How can I make it visible please?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have implemented Navigation Drawer, and having trouble in calling tabhost in fragment.

Try the following steps.

1. Create a parent fragment to hold the tab, in this fragment add as many tabs as you want to add. (In this example I am showing two tabs).
2. Create the fragments that you have added in the tabs. (Fragment1, Fragment2)

ParentFragment.java

```
public class ParentView extends Fragment {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.fragment_parent_view);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary_dark));  // if you want to set color of tab

        Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
        arg1.putString("aim", "passingvalues1");

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("NAME1"),
                Fragment1.class, arg1);

        Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();
        arg2.putString("aim", "passingvalues2");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Name2"),
                Fragment2.class, arg2);

         return mTabHost;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mTabHost = null;
    }


}
```

fragment_parent_view.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xx.xx.xx.ParentFragment">


</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment1.java

```
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment 
    {
        private LinearLayout llLayout;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            llLayout    = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
            return llLayout;
        }
    }
```

Fragment2.java

```
    public class Fragment2 extends Fragment 
    {
        private LinearLayout llLayout;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            llLayout    = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
            return llLayout;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have try it but I have a BURG "unfortunedly stopped" when I call the fragment

Comment: is there a specific use to call the fragment in this case?