# Tabs with in the Tabs in android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

I just want to implements Tabs with in the Tabs. If it is possible than please share the code

See image below for reference

[image]

Comment: you have to make tab inside fragment

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864778/how-to-load-tabhost-in-a-fragment/38865160#38865160

Comment: I tried..but there is an error. In this link there is an adapter class . by importing that class it implement several methods which is not there in the code. I am confused which adapter class i have to import [Widget.Adapter or Recyclerview.Adapter]

Comment: nope below which i have created that one

Comment: now see i  have updated code name so you will not confused

Comment: Your question seems not to be clear. what do you mean by tab inside tabs ? could you elaborate little bit more. I mean what is the purpose and flow.

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper Look at her question mentioning that tab inside tabs and your link seems suggesting `Tab Host` integration in android.

Comment: there is only one confusion I have that you need 3 different tabs  inside TAB 1 or the same in remaining TAB 1 , TAB 2 TAB 3

Comment: @jaydroider dear when she click on first tab it load fragment right..? so i have suggest her for that same. tabhost inside fragment.

Comment: @jaydroider have any other way to achieve this.?

Comment: @VaishaliGoel have you solved  your problem...?

Comment: yess... Thanks ..for help..:)

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper.. that is ViewPagerAdapter instead of PagerAdapter

Comment: @VaishaliGoel yes below i have created class for that. that class name is pagerAdapter.

Comment: hi @Vaishali can you post the whole code you used as answer here it will be helpful for others and it will also upvotes your reputation

Comment: @UmarAta see that link which i have posted in that whole code is there.

Comment: I am not asked  you sir

Comment: hwy.. code is fine but m stuck in bind function of ButterKnife class. It cannot resolve bind function.. Please help me.. @AndroidDeveloper

Comment: if she did the same I want then why I asked or search it else where

Comment: I post my answer, when i complete this.. @UmarAta

Comment: @VaishaliGoel its 3rd party lib. for binding all componants. you can simply bind viewpager

Comment: yes.. i add  'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0' dependecy. but it not resolve bind and unbind method. What else i do.?  @AndroidDeveloper

Comment: @VaishaliGoel  i have removed that code now check

Comment: @VaishaliGoel now solved??

Comment: Thank you soo much ..It worked.. :). .. I surely upvote you..but what is the funcionality of bind and unbind method?? @AndroidDeveloper

Comment: @VaishaliGoel its method of butterknife  see this link you get how  its is used. http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: @VaishaliGoel can you please post the complete answer here

Comment: Yes it will be great if you post the answer for this. Thanks!

Comment: Use [TabLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout).

Comment: see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015713/50-android-replace-fragments-inside-viewpager/39056616#39056616 at comment of Answer I implement such a things.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer of my question. I set the tabs with in the Tabs. Basically set the tab in fragment:

My java code:

```
public class SD extends Fragment {
View view;
PagerAdapter adapter;
public SD() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
```

///Here we have to pass ChildFragmentManager instead of FragmentManager.

```
    adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Sim1Detail(), "Sim 1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Sim2Detail(), "Sim 2");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sd, container, false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // ButterKnife.bind(getActivity(), view);
    final ViewPager viewPager = ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
   // ButterKnife.unbind(getActivity);
}

static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

here it is ..

Comment: add **compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'** you just add this statement in your app gradle file and if answer is helpful to you then plz upvote it.. @UmarAta